# Submit Form Data to Google Sheet using AJAX

Tags: ajax, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cors

I am trying to Submit Form Data to Google Sheet using AJAX.

My HTML Form code is like below

```
<form id="test-form">
<input type="text" name="1" />
<div class="question">
<button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="activebtn showElement">
      Submit
</button>
</div>
</form>
```

My jQuery code is like below

```
var $form = $('form#test-form');
var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyC_o4JsVtdevTrjeBOzSi6HJEJjzTzY/exec';

$('#submit-form').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        data: $form.serializeObject(),
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

My Google App Script code is like below

```
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

//  Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.
  
  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    
    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
});
```

I am facing `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin`  issue.

[image]

Web App publishing settings

[image]

Comment: I don’t see any authorization headers. Are you doing this from a website or a web app?If from a website I think you may need to set up a service account. And have you loaded jquery?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Thanks @Cooper for your reply. I am following this(https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175) tutorial. I am doing this from a Website. Yes, I have loaded jQuery. 

I don't know how to provide minimal reproducible example.  Thanks.

Comment: Well now‘s a good time to learn

Comment: Thanks @Cooper for your reply. Yes, I am learning. I am doing this Form Submission to Google Sheet first time. Thanks.

Comment: Try with crossDomain: true in the ajax call

Comment: What are the settings that you used to publish your script as a web application?

Comment: Thanks @Rubén. Here are the settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROKVl.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't authorized the script. What you need to do is, go to the script editor where you have written the doGet function and then run it from there. It will be then asking you to authorize the script.

Please also note that, when you make any changes to the script and save the code, it will not be working correctly until you save a new version and then publish it.

Comment: Thanks @Anees Hameed. I am new to Google App Script. Could you please guide me to follow your suggestion ?